# React - Static Data Storage (Memory Implications)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, memory-management

Currently developing a SPA (React - CRA, TypeScript) that is dependent on a lot of static (immutable) data that will be searched, filtered, and displayed across the application.

Was given guidance by my tech lead to not use a database/backend to keep the application lightweight/simple. I'm looking at storing around ~30 of these static data points in a module (array of objects) and importing that module wherever that data needs to be accessed across the application (shallow copy within high-level components). With the following structure:

```
SampleObject {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string (can contain up to 1000 characters);
    homePageUrl: string;
    signInUrl: string;
    imagePath: string;
}
```

Could I potentially run into any memory/performance optimization issues (locally on client/browser) with this structure and volume of data (may grow to ~50 objects)? I expect not, but just want to confirm. I'm aware of alternatives to store this static data like JSON, etc, but figured I could get away with storing this as an exported array.

Researching similar questions across multiple forums, websites, and case studies.